# Will NSManagedObjectContext live long enough to perform all blocks submitted with -performBlock:?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, object-lifetime

Consider following code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *parentContext = ... // global context, exists as long as app runs
MyEntity *parentEntity = ... // parentEntity is in parentContext

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
context.parentContext = parentContext;

MyEntity *entity = [context objectWithID:parentEntity.objectID];

[context performBlock:^{
    // context is not referenced inside this block

    // Imagine entity is a fault, i.e. `entity.myStringProperty` is not cached.
    // Question: will context still be alive to fetch data from parent context?
    // i.e. does context live as long as its queue has pending blocks or block being run now?
    NSLog(@"%@", entity.myStringProperty);
}];

// context is no longer referenced by code, i.e. it may dealloc
```

Will `context` still be alive to fetch data from `parentContext`? i.e. does `context` live as long as its queue has pending blocks or block being run now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

You can assume that as long as an object is doing some work it will be kept in memory. The context is a fully functioning context that should be able to fill faults as expected.

Comment: is it documented somewhere, or is it your experience? I feel like this would be a natural thing for context to live long enough, but I want to be sure because otherwise it will lead to bugs that are hard to reproduce.

Comment: It is my experience; and I think it would be unlikely to be documented. It seems obvious that an active thread belonging to an object cannot allow the object to be released.